# Group of invertible elements, isomorphic to $Z_4$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic

The group $f(8)$ of invertible elements in the ring $Z_{10}$ has four elements, $f(10) = \{ [1,], [3], [7], [9]\}$. Is this group isomorphic to $Z_4$ or to the symmetry group of the rectangle?

Attempt: I have tried to compare the multiplication modulo $10$, and the addition modulo $4$ table. I am not sure if I am on the right track.

Please can someone help me.

Thank you

Comment: did you see that [3] generate the others?

Comment: No, I don't see that. Can you please give an example?

Comment: Do you know what a cyclic group is? Is $(\mathbb{Z}_4; +)$ cyclic? Is $(f(10), \times)$ cyclic?

Comment: In $V_4$ (the symmetries of the rectangle), every element is its own inverse...

Comment: Not yet, my professor has not taught cyclic groups yet. So I thought maybe there is another way to solve it by looking at their tables

Comment: It is possible with the tables. The hint about $[3]$ generating the others means you should be comparing $[3]$ in $Z_{10}$ with $[1]$ in $Z_4$ since $[1]$ generates the elements in $Z_4$.

Comment: Do you mean, [3]^0 = e, [3]^1 = [3], [3]^2 = [9], [3]^3 = [27] ? and 1 + 0 = 0, 1 + 1 = 2, 1 + 2 = 3 , 1 + 3 = 0 ? and compare?

Comment: Basically. You can try the same with the symmetry group if you really want to see the difference.